# How do I specify a many-to-many relationship in EF Core where the connection table is part of a schema?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

On https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#joining-relationships-configuration they have the following example of how to specify a many-to-many relationship in Entity Framework Core:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
    .HasMany(p => p.Tags)
    .WithMany(p => p.Posts)
    .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
        "PostTag",
        j => j
            .HasOne<Tag>()
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("TagId")
            .HasConstraintName("FK_PostTag_Tags_TagId")
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade),
        j => j
            .HasOne<Post>()
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("PostId")
            .HasConstraintName("FK_PostTag_Posts_PostId")
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade));
```

How do I do the same thing, but specify that `PostTag` is part of a schema other than the default one?

For instance, `Test.PostTag` and `[Test].[PostTag]` do not work. When trying to access the resource, it just results in the exception `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 'PostTag'.'` being thrown. So it seems to ignore the schema name `Test` when I try to specify it.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use an explicit `Entity<PostTag>` instead of using EF's (poorly designed, imo)  `m:m` "feature"?

Comment: @Dai Haven't thought about it, but thank you for the suggestion. Do you know how to rewrite the example? Otherwise I will give it a shot when I'm back at work.

Comment: There's an example at the bottom of this page: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration

Comment: `.UsingEntity` returns an `EntityTypeBuilder` which you can use to further customise the table `.UsingEntity(...).ToTable("PostTag", "Test")`, or there's an overload which takes a `Action<EntityTypeBuilder>` argument if you prefer a lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was to do what they have written on the page https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration. In their example, they have the following two classes:

```cs
public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
}  
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
}
```

And then they made the following class to connect them through a many-to-many relationship:

```cs
public class BookCategory
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

And then they have the following configuration:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<BookCategory>()
        .HasKey(bc => new { bc.BookId, bc.CategoryId });  
    modelBuilder.Entity<BookCategory>()
        .HasOne(bc => bc.Book)
        .WithMany(b => b.BookCategories)
        .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.BookId);  
    modelBuilder.Entity<BookCategory>()
        .HasOne(bc => bc.Category)
        .WithMany(c => c.BookCategories)
        .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.CategoryId);
}
```

In my case, I configured the connection class like this:

```cs
internal class AccountRuleEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<CompAccountRule>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AccountRule> builder)
    {
        builder
            .ToTable("AccountRules", "Compliance");
        builder
            .HasKey(x => new { x.AccountId, x.RuleInstanceId });
        builder
            .HasOne(x => x.Account)
            .WithMany(x => x.AccountRules)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.AccountId);
        builder
            .HasOne(x => x.RuleInstance)
            .WithMany(x => x.AccountRules)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.RuleInstanceId);
    }
}
```

`Account` belongs to the default namespace, `RuleInstance` belongs to the `Compliance` namespace, and this connection table `AccountRule` also belongs to the `Compliance` namespace, which is I'm able to configure through the statement `builder.ToTable("AccountRules", "Compliance");`.